# Reload grid is not working while applying filter in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

**Grid Reload is not working after getting response from backend , but i could see the filter applied on grid after clicking on the any sorting button in grid.**

*Here i have declared the filter code statically.*

Grid code is below

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({ 
url:'getList.php?mode=result_list', 
datatype: "json",
height: 255, 
width: 600, 
colNames:['Index','Name', 'Code','Result'], 
colModel:[
{name:'item_id',index:'item_id', width:65, sorttype:'integer',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','le','lt','gt','ge']}},
{name:'item',index:'item', width:150, sorttype:'string',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}},
{name:'item_cd',index:'item_cd', width:100} ,
{name:'result',index:'result', width:100,sorttype:'string',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']} ], 
rowNum:50, 
rowTotal: 200,
loadonce:true, 
mtype: "GET", 
rownumWidth: 40, 
gridview: true, 
pager: '#pager451', 
sortname:'item_id', 
viewrecords: true, 
sortorder: "asc", 
 loadComplete: function() {
 $("#foo").trigger( "click" );
 },
caption: "Loading data from server at once" });
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators : true});
```

Foo Click function jquery is below

```
$("#foo").on( "click", function() {
                    var grid=$("#grid");
                    var dddf={"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"item_id","op":"eq","data":"123"}]};

                    jqgselectFilter(dddf);


                });
                function jqgselectFilter(myfilter){
                    grid = jQuery("#grid");
                    //console.log(myfilter);
                    grid[0].p.search = myfilter['rules'].length>0;
                    jQuery.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(myfilter)});
                    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);    
                }
```

Comment: Could you describe the problem more clear? Which results you expect and which one you have? Do you need to apply *local filtering and sorting* the data immediately after loading from the server? Should the filter be applied **once**? What meaning have the element with `id="foo"`? Where it exist on the page?

Comment: Oleg Very thanks for viewing my question.i want to apply the filter after loading the response from server programmatically(Filter need to apply one time its enough for me). i don't want filter to be applied after sorting. I have reached my functionality 90 % but grid is not reload that is only issue Oleg.The Foo function is user's previous time using filter json value(column filter JSON stored in DB) getting from DB. The foo value i will trigger grid loadComplete time.

Comment: I have used your previous answer about reload grid options but its not working.I could see the filter applied on grid after clicking on the any sorting button in grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but I suppose that you could fix the problem by modifying `loadComplete` to the following:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    if ($(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") !== "local") {
        // initial loading from the server
         setTimeout(function () {
             $("#foo").trigger("click");
         }, 50);
    }
}
```

You use `datatype: "json"` together with `loadonce: true`. So the `datatype` will be changed to `"local"` *after* the loading from the server and *after* calling of `loadComplete`. So one can test whether the `datatype` is not equal to `"local"` to detect the first loading. I placed the action, executed in case of the first loading, inside of `setTimeout` to allow jqGrid to finish the initial processing (with changing the `datatype` for  example) before.